# Getting mouse co-ordinates using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse-coordinates

I am building a breakout game using jQuery and the `<canvas>` element. To control the paddle, it will follow the mouse. So I need to get the mouse co-ordinates in my `drawPaddle()` method.

Looking on the jQuery site it has examples like this:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
});
```

Which does what I want, but I don't want to add another function to my project like this. This is my `drawPaddle()` method:

```
function drawPaddle() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(paddleX, paddleY, 150, 10);
    c.closePath();
    c.fill();
    // Get mouse position and update paddleX and paddleY here
}
```

So I need to find a way to get the mouse position whenever the `drawPaddle()` is called, and not whenever the mouse is moved on page like `$(document).mousemove(function(e){`
 does.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('canvas').mousemove(function(e){
    drawPaddle(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});


function drawPaddle(paddleX, paddleY) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(paddleX, paddleY, 150, 10);
    c.closePath();
    c.fill();
}
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid tbh. I just wanted to grab the mouse co-ordinates from inside my `drawPaddle` function only. But it seems there is no other way.

Comment: what is the event you're going to use to trigger the `drawPaddle()` or when are you going to call the `drawPaddle()`?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to do

```
var where = {}
$('canvas').mousemove(function(e){
    where.x = e.pageX
    where.y = e.pageY;
});
```

and then use wherex,y in the function

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do it without an event. I know no field in JavaScript that stores that information globally. Some time ago I had the same problem and did that with the `mousemove` event because I found no other solution. Maybe some browser implement a way to get those coordinates but I don't know.

But maybe you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on your canvas to enable/disable the mouse position capturing. That will reduce the of function calls.